# Changing screen-resolution by ubuntu console

Tags: ubuntu, resolution

I changed my ubuntu screen-resolution and now it's everything black and I can't change it againd to the old resolution. What do I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
xrandr -s  800x600
```

Adjust resolution itself as necessary.  This works if you've got a running X11.

If the GUI won't start at all, you may want to try removing `xorg.conf`; as far as I remember it should be automatically regenerated. But just in case, let's just move it aside instead of deleting it.

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
```

Comment: the second command has to be executed as root, I suggest adding sudo in front of it..

Comment: Good suggestion! I edited my post appropriately and upvoted you, thank you.